# How do I apply a stylesheet just to the iPhone (and not IE), without browser sniffing?

Tags: iphone, css, internet-explorer, ios, mobile-safari

I’d like to apply a stylesheet exclusively to the iPhone, without doing browser sniffing (via the user-agent string) on the server or via JavaScript.

I particularly don’t want Internet Explorer to apply the stylesheet. Apple’s suggested code for applying an iPhone-specific stylesheet, i.e.:

```
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="small-device.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

seems to cause the stylesheet to be applied by IE 7 and 6.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use Apple’s suggested code, but wrap it in conditional comments to hide it from IE:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="small-device.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Credit I think to [Sitepoint’s iPhone development article](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/iphone-development-12-tips/) for this.