# My html site is not displaying in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I am using the following CSS link code on my site:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index_files/front.css" media="all" type="text/css" >
```

and also the following code

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
```

Here is my site links - http://www.etutorbd.com/shopi/. It's displaying properly in desktop browser but It's not displaying in mobile browser. I have checked in my android phone. I have found this answered [My phone is not displaying the mobile oriented version of my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135096/my-phone-is-not-displaying-the-mobile-oriented-version-of-my-site) but It's not working for me. I didn't found any console error. I had a problems like "Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest' ". But I have fixed that. What am I doing wrong here?  Is there any jQuery or CSS media type issues.

Comment: It shows up on my Android phone.

Comment: Really? Can you shear a screenshot?

Comment: http://gutfullofbeer.net/so_ss.png

Comment: @Pointy Yeah. That is the problems. The website only showing the top header content. The same content showing in my phone. But the site has many content to show. Can you tell me, How can I fix the problems?

Comment: Well the only way I know to diagnose those problems is by using remote debugging via Chrome (like with [weinre](https://github.com/apache/cordova-weinre)).

Comment: Have there anyone to answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove this from your HTML body:

```
overflow: hidden; height: 100%; font-size: 81.44%;
```

if you really need it, add it to your CSS and then use media-queries to disable it on mobile sizes

EDIT with code:

```
body{overflow:hidden /*use it only if needed, otherwise remove it */}
@media(max-width:768px){
body{overflow: auto; height: 100%; font-size: 81.44% /* change if needed */;}
}
```

Comment: Can you give me the media queries code with correction the css.

Comment: It's not working. But I just removed the "beforeAnimation" class and not it's working.