# How can you hide CSS from the iPhone, but not other browsers?

Tags: iphone, css, ios, media-queries

I know how to hide CSS from all browsers *except* the iPhone: see [How do I apply a stylesheet just to the iPhone (and not IE), without browser sniffing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809532/how-do-i-apply-a-stylesheet-just-to-the-iphone-and-not-ie-without-browser-snif)

But: how do I hide CSS from the iPhone, but not other browsers?

Comment: Meanwhile, an even better answer is found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47818418/214500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up going with a slightly different, and very ridiculous, solution that uses media queries and `getComputedStyle` to redirect to a mobile site if we’re on an iPhone-like device.

```
<style media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)">html{border-top-style:dashed;}</style>

<script>
if(window.location.search.indexOf("?m=t")==-1 && window.getComputedStyle) {
    var mobile = false;

    if(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0],null).getPropertyValue("border-top-style")=="dashed") {
        var mobile = true;
    }

    if(mobile) {
        window.location.replace(window.location+"?m=t");
    }
}
</script>
```

I’m sure I got the `getComputedStyle` idea on Stack Overflow, but I can’t remember where.

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly use [`@media queries`](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/return-of-the-mobile-stylesheet):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="noniPhoneStylesheet1.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width:490px)" />
```

Which would automatically exclude iPhone browsers from downloading that particular stylesheet (the iPhone's screen width being 480px); so putting any styles you want to hide from the iPhone into that stylesheet should work. Although, obviously, it'll also block that stylesheet from other devices that respect media-queries and have a screen width below 490px.

Comment: And...here's hoping it really works... =0 (I've not tried it, just seems like it *should*...)

Comment: @Paul, any luck with this, or feedback?

Comment: @David: righty — unfortunately, this also hides it from Firefox 3.0 and IE 9 (and presumably lower), so at the moment, it’s not a goer for sites with a mainstream audience. Opera 9.0 and Safari 3.0 are fine though, so once Firefox 3.0 has died out enough, this method plus conditional comments for IE could work a treat.

Comment: @Paul: hmm. That's an oddly contrarian implementation from Firefox =/ Were you able to find an alternative method?

Comment: @David: I think it’s correct — I believe the spec says that if a browser doesn’t understand part of a media query, it should disregard the stylesheet.

Comment: @Paul, my comment was to Firefox not having already implemented `@media queries` it surprises me that they're not as near the bleeding edge of CSS implementation as I (unfairly) expect of them.

Comment: @David: sure — that particular media query works fine as of Firefox 3.5, released on 30th June 2009 (just over a year after Firefox 3.0), so they caught up eventually.

Answer (score 1):

You can still do the conditional check, for iPhones append the iPhone CSS otherwise your normal CSS.

```
var agent=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isIPhone = ((agent.indexOf('iphone')!=-1);

if (isIPhone)
  document.createElement("style")... //iPhone CSS
else
  document.createElement("style")... //normal CSS
```

Comment: Sure, although that does mean you’re using JavaScript to apply stylesheets in every browser.

Comment: You can also do this server side if it's not just an HTML page by checking the http_user_agent.

Answer (score 0):

Or a simple redirect to a page without the CSS, or use PHP to detect iPhones and deliver them a page without the style — something with a flow of:

```
if iPhone {
    echo //page without CSS
else {
    echo //page with CSS
}
```