# CSS media query to target only iOS devices

Tags: css, media-queries

Is there a @media query to target only devices running iOS?

For example:

```
@media (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:768px) {
    #nav {
        yada: yada;
    }
}
```

Would this also alter the behavior of the page on Android devices with these device widths?

Comment: all devices not only IOS

Comment: Why you need this? You can get the user agent with javascript and depending on the result you can include a special css file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839809/detect-iphone-ipad-purely-by-css

Comment: @webcodecs - as a general rule (see: [Rule of Least Power](https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/leastPower.html)) if anything can be achieved via HTML or CSS instead of JS, then it should be implemented via the former technology. It's not true that we should _never_ turn to JS for presentational effects, but if CSS can deliver the result that we need, then JS is superfluous.

Answer (score 460, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
  /* CSS specific to iOS devices */ 
}

@supports not (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
  /* CSS for other than iOS devices */ 
}
```

YMMV.

It works because only **Safari Mobile** implements `-webkit-touch-callout`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-touch-callout

Please note that `@supports` does not work in IE. IE will skip both of the above `@support` blocks above. To find out more see https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/08/using-feature-queries-in-css/. It is recommended to **not** use `@supports not` because of this.

What about Chrome or Firefox on iOS? The reality is these are just skins over the WebKit rendering engine. Hence the above works everywhere on iOS as long as iOS policy does not change. See 2.5.6 in [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements).

**Warning: iOS may remove support for this in any new iOS release in the coming years. You SHOULD try a bit harder to not need the above CSS. An earlier version of this answer used `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` but a new iOS version removed it.** As a commenter pointed out, there are other options to choose from: Go to [Supported CSS Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html) and search for "Safari on iOS".

Comment: -webkit-overflow-scrolling only supported in Safari, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling

Comment: And this ignores Android?

Comment: This is awesome... Thanks for this, I know it's not a standard approach but sometimes you do need special rules for iOS because... well because they are apple.

Comment: @carl Yes this ignores Android simply because -webkit-overflow-scrolling is only supported by Safari Mobile.

Comment: try it with android 5.0 and iphone 5, and its fine, thanks

Comment: I tried this in an iOS 8.1 simulator and it does not work. I could be misinterpreting but I believe that @supports only works in iOS 10 or greater.  https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries

Comment: Yes, I suppose you are right. iOS 8 is really old. @supports is a relatively new syntax.

Comment: I don't understand why this was accepted as an answer:
If you use Chrome on iOS, this code doesn't work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling

Comment: @Johnny All browsers on iOS are based on Safari's Webkit engine: blog.chromium.org/2016/01/… Chrome for iOS is basically Safari with stuff added on top.

Comment: Sorry, messed up link & can't edit. See https://blog.chromium.org/2016/01/a-faster-more-stable-chrome-on-ios.html and https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/01/new-chrome-for-ios-is-finally-as-fast-and-stable-as-safari/

Comment: tested in on chrome and safari on iPhone, at the moment both work

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with iOS 13 (on iPad) anymore since they dropped support for `-webkit-overflow-scrolling`. Has anyone come up with a new solution for iOS 13?

Comment: That's news. Hmm...

Comment: @JoshLyon `-webkit-touch-callout` still works. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60220757/1038456.

Comment: Hopefully they fix the horrible `select` styling before they remove this...

Comment: If this ever changes again, go to https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html and search for "Safari on iOS only"

Comment: The above label at the top of this is incorrect, "This question already has answers here: Detect iPhone/iPad purely by css (5 answers) Closed last year." THIS answer can be used inside the other answer to further delineate for iOS. Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: -webkit-text-size-adjust currently detects ios safari also

Answer (score 18):

I don't know about targeting iOS as a whole, but to target iOS Safari specifically:

```
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
   /* CSS specific to iOS devices */ 
}

@supports not (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
   /* CSS for other than iOS devices */ 
}
```

Apparently as of iOS 13 `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` no longer responds to `@supports`, but `-webkit-touch-callout` still does. Of course that could change in the future...

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned above, the short answer is no. But I'm in need of something similar in the app I'm working on now, yet the areas where the CSS needs to be different are limited to very specific areas of a page.

If you're like me and don't need to serve up an entirely different stylesheet, another option would be to detect a device running iOS in the way described in this question's selected answer: [Detect if device is iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios)

Once you've detected the iOS device you could add a class to the area you're targeting using Javascript (eg. the `document.getElementsByTagName("yourElementHere")[0].setAttribute("class", "iOS-device");`, jQuery, PHP or whatever, and style that class accordingly using the pre-existing stylesheet.

```
.iOS-device {
      style-you-want-to-set: yada;
}
```

Comment: This is what I used. Our code knows that we are on iPhone so in JS we change the font-size for text-area to 16px, which looks good and does not affect other browsers (desktop including)

Answer (score 8):

Short answer No. 
CSS is not specific to brands.

Below are the articles to implement for iOS using media only.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

Infact you can use PHP, Javascript to detect the iOS browser and according to that you can call CSS file. 
For instance

http://www.kevinleary.net/php-detect-ios-mobile-users/