# Media query min-width: 980px exclude ipad landscape?

Tags: css, media-queries

In a mobile first approach, is it possible to declare a min-width: 980px, but not apply this css for ipad landscape, without duplicating any previous css before this media query. So, ignore the media if ipad landscape, but apply when just min-width: 980px

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS media query target only iOS devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102792/css-media-query-target-only-ios-devices)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102792/css-media-query-target-only-ios-devices