# Using css rules to target just Safari browser on iPad's

Tags: ios, css, ipad, css-selectors, mobile-safari

I am trying to fix an issue that only appears on my website when browsing using an Safari on an iPad, what is the best/cleanest solution to run some CSS to just target that particular combination of device and browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS media query target only iOS devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102792/css-media-query-target-only-ios-devices)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do some feature/device sniffing to add a class to the body tag to identify the browser.
If you describe what the problem is in iPad Safari, I could maybe give you a solution to fix the problem without targeting that specific browser, meaning the CSS would apply to all browsers but doesn't break anything.