# Email template - Trying to target Apple devices only or Android devices only

Tags: android, ios, css, html-email, email

I'm using this rule

```
@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch) and (color:#ffff) {
 /* Insert CSS here */
 img[class=iosButton]{display: block !important;}
 td[class=iosButton]{display: block !important;}
 img[class=androidButton]{display: none !important;}
 }
```

So, I'm showing by default the Android link to the Google App Store.
And when matching that CSS rule then it means I'm in an Apple device or Apple Mail... I'm replacing the Android by the Apple stuff. Has anyone experienced any similar scenario? Have you gone beyond this point? Any target only Linux, MacOs, Windows scenario (might be desktop breakpoint will do the trick)?

The same I'd like to achieve but for Android devices. I already have visited some resources with a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102792/css-media-query-target-only-ios-devices).

Comment: Some versions of Android do not support `@media` queries. You can target IOS and build an email for Android with media queries for IOS enhancements.

Comment: Adding to Gwally's comment, some android devices will be hard to find with media queries or a lot will be required. You can have a link for download and let the page decide which device is making the request and take it from there.

Comment: you coudl trawl https://howtotarget.email/ but to be honest I think it would be better to let the user decide. What about those people who have both apple and android devices? Or one for work but another for personal? Or what about people forwarding the emails to a person with a different setup?