# Targeting handheld style sheets

Tags: iphone, css

I have how would i only target iphone? I have tried

```
media="handheld, only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
```

but it wont display my menu? 
I have two menus - one for web browsers and one for mobile web. Im guessing as iphone only reads the 'screen' type that is why it is displaying. I have specified in my main site css not to display my mobile menu and in my mobile style sheet I have specified not to display the web navigation? 
Any ideas?!
Link to my site is www.therisingsuntarporley.co.uk

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for targeting iPhone looks right (see [How do I apply a stylesheet just to the iPhone (and not IE), without browser sniffing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809532/how-do-i-apply-a-stylesheet-just-to-the-iphone-and-not-ie-without-browser-snif) for some improvements). However, iPhones will display *both* the regular stylesheets *and* the mobile-specific ones. To show the menu, you need to add `display: block;` to the `.menu` element in `mobile.css`.

Comment: Thank you! How would i stop the 'mobile' only menu from displaying on the web version?

Comment: If the mobile menu is hidden in the regular stylesheet, and mobile.css is applied to iPhones, then the mobile menu would only appear on mobile devices.